# NUMBER(10,2) not equal to check in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, numbers, conditional-statements

I have a Number field in Table(Oracle) as follows

```
TEST_HOURS NUMBER(10,2)
```

when i try the following SQL it does not work

```
select t.test_hours from test_hours t where
where (t.test_hours != 1 or t.test_hours is not null)
and t.id = 11
```

when i remove this `(t.test_hours != 1 or t.test_hours != null)` it works fine but when i include the above line then it does not fetch data and there is no `error`.

could someone help me to resolve this pls.

Thanks

Comment: This condition seems pointless `t.test_hours != 1 or t.test_hours != null`.  What are you trying to get?

Comment: You can not do a comparison with `null`. Always use `is null` or `is not null`.

Comment: @vkp tried with is not null, it did not help

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff i am trying to check if test_hours has the value of 1, if it has the value 1 then dont fetch the row if not fetch the row, i will pass the value dynamic for testing i gave with the value but id not help

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in Egor's comment, your condition on the column in question has no sense. Also, you should use `IS NOT NULL` or `IS NULL`, not `!=`. When you use `!=`, and whatever is on the left hand side is null, then the result will be equal to `NULL`, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Even with the `IS NOT NULL`, your condition is invalid, because the condition will always be `TRUE` for `test_hours` equal to 1, because:

```
test_hours != 1 FALSE
OR
test_hours IS NOT NULL TRUE
```

hence the result will be TRUE.

You probably want to use a different condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want *and*, not *or*:

```
select t.test_hours
from test_hours t
where (t.test_hours <> 1 and t.test_hours is not null) and t.id = 11
```

By the way, the comparison to `NULL` is unnecessary, because it would fail.  So a simpler version is:

```
select t.test_hours
from test_hours t
where t.test_hours <> 1 and t.id = 11
```